# What is the meaning of java's intrinsic object lock has a single associated conditional object

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, synchronized

I'm studying java concurrency and came across the `synchronized` keyword.

When comparing to a `ReentrantLock` object and a conditional object, a lock can have one or more associated condition objects, the intrinsic object lock has a single associated condition.

What is the meaning and purpose of having a single conditional object?

Answer (score 0):

Intrinsic locking means that you don't have to create an object to synchronize your methods on.

So you don't have to create an explicit `Object lock = new Object();` or using `ReentrantLock` to synchronize your access on a shared mutable type.

`ReentrantLock`comes with some convenience features like tryLock, lock with timeout, read-write lock....